# How to Individuate an element of a list using reflection?

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection, properties

I have a `List<T>` of element and a `PropertyInfo` with a list of the property of `T`.

How can I identify a single property of an element in a loop ?

Ideally :

```
List<T>[i].PropertyInfo[y].Name
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using reflection to get values from properties from a list of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710156/using-reflection-to-get-values-from-properties-from-a-list-of-a-class)

Comment: No. I read the post you have mentioned. My problem is different. I have a Generic List of element and the array of its properties. No nested classes. I want only to get to enumerate all the element of the list with its properties using the infos I have.

Comment: is that not what the accepted answer does? you cast your list to an `IList`, use foreach on it (or use the `Item` method), and use your propertyinfos to get each value? That's as good as it gets, I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood the question currently and you're looking to match the two collections, then you could use the type of the property info(Has a property type Property) and the typeof(T).
For efficiency i would recommend creating a dynamic method that would be cached for future usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the type of the properties, you must use the property:

```
PropertyInfo.PropertyType
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a solution like the one in the post "Get property value from string using reflection in C#".